# Does Flex HttpService support https with client authentication

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ssl, air

I want to access secure service(rest style https) for credit card detail in AIR app so I want to authenticate .PEM certificate. how to use addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate() method because it accept DER encoded x509 certificate, do i need to pass private rsa key and certificate separately to addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate() method.

I tried using TLSsocket using as3crypto i connect to host for some time and then i receive close event.

if SWF running in browser do we still need to pass certificate/key or not

how flex deal  keystore and certstore or uses its own?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!